# Calculating and comparing a Date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to figure out a way to take a date in a table in SQL, check if it's older than the value in another column and possibly output the difference.

For Example:

ColA has a standard SQL date stamp of 2011-12-12 04:10:00.000
ColB has a number in it such as 10
I'd like to be able to compare todays date to the date in (ColA + the value in ColB)

ColB's values are in days so adding the 10 above would mean ColA's date + 10 would be:
2011-12-22 04:10:00.000.

I'm trying to figure out how to compare todays date with this date to see if how many days from today it is. In this case (12-22-2011) it would be 45 days ago.

Hopefully this explanation isn't too confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DATEDIFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) and [`DATEADD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) to manipulate and compare SQL Server dates/datetimes.

e.g

```
DATEADD(day, 10, ColA)
```

and

```
IF DATEDIFF(day, DATEADD(day, 10, ColA), GETDATE()) > SomeNumberofDays
```

Comment: Is there a way to test this without modifying the table? I'd like to do something like: WHERE GETDATE () > (YEAR(ColA) AND MONTH(ColA) AND (DAY(ColA) + ColB). Basically only returning rows that are more recent than ColA's date + the number of days in ColB.

Comment: My examples do not modify any table, nor should you; you are comparing not updating. The comparison in my answer can do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Once I looked more into the two functions and tested them it became clear as to how they work. Thanks again!